# APP in Java not responding when enabling Bluetooth in a device in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-permissions, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to design a simple Application in Java in Android Studio to enable Bluetooth on the phone.

Basically, I have two buttons (to enable and disable the Bluetooth).

I've tried to use the new way of implementing `startActivityForResult` as this method is being deprecated.

I'm quite new at Java and not sure how I may debug the code properly in Android Studio. However, the app is not responding to the `ON` button and it's close when click on `OFF` button.

Most probably is there an error on the code but cannot see where.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.project.btseat;
import android.Manifest;

import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button ON;
    Button OFF;
    BluetoothAdapter myBluetoothAdapter;

    Intent btEnablingIntent;

    int requestCodeForEnable;

    Log log = null;

    private ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions multiplePermissionsContract;
    private ActivityResultLauncher<String[]> multiplePermissionLauncher;

    final String[] PERMISSIONS = {
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ON = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btON);
        OFF = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btOFF);
        myBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        btEnablingIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        requestCodeForEnable = 100;

        multiplePermissionsContract = new ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions();
        multiplePermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(multiplePermissionsContract, isGranted -> {
            Log.d("PERMISSIONS", "Launcher result: " + isGranted.toString());
            if (isGranted.containsValue(false)) {
                Log.d("PERMISSIONS", "At least one of the permissions was not granted, launching again...");
                multiplePermissionLauncher.launch(PERMISSIONS);
            }
        });

        askPermissions(multiplePermissionLauncher);
        bluetoothONMethod();
        bluetoothOFFMethod();


    }

    private void askPermissions(ActivityResultLauncher<String[]> multiplePermissionLauncher){
        if (!hasPermissions(PERMISSIONS)) {
            log.d("PERMISSIONS", "Launching multiple contract permission launcher for ALL required permissions");
            multiplePermissionLauncher.launch(PERMISSIONS);
        } else {
            Log.d("PERMISSIONS", "All permissions are already granted");
        }
    }
    private boolean hasPermissions(String[] permissions) {
        if (permissions != null){
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.d("PERMISSIONS", "Permission is not granted: " + permission);
                }
                return false;
            }
        return true;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth is Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth Enabling Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void bluetoothOFFMethod() {
        OFF.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (myBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                myBluetoothAdapter.disable();
            }
        });
    }

    private void bluetoothONMethod(){
        ON.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (myBluetoothAdapter==null){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth Adapter does not support on this device",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    if(!myBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
                      someActivityResultLauncher.launch(btEnablingIntent);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml (relevant permissions)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="true"/>


...
```

logcat logs:

```
2023-09-07 14:55:27.962  7824-8060  cr_CronetU...estContext com....android.googlequicksearchbox  E  Exception in upload method
                                                                                                    com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.r.d: Error code: 262182
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.ab.bk.d(PG:5)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.c.a.ar.d(PG:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.c.a.bo.b(PG:5)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.c.a.e.a(PG:2)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.libraries.gsa.c.a.a.run(PG:2)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.bf.execute(PG:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.i(PG:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.l(PG:12)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.cancel(PG:8)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.m(PG:2)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.j.a(PG:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.l(PG:3)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.cancel(PG:8)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.m(PG:2)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.j.a(PG:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.l(PG:3)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.cancel(PG:8)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.m(PG:2)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.j.a(PG:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.l(PG:3)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.cancel(PG:8)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.m(PG:2)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.j.a(PG:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.l(PG:3)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.cancel(PG:8)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.m(PG:2)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.c.a(PG:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.l(PG:3)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.cancel(PG:8)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.bu.cancel(PG:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.cancel(PG:17)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.bk.b.h.run(PG:2)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.bf.execute(PG:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.i(PG:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.l(PG:12)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.cancel(PG:8)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.m(PG:2)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.j.a(PG:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.l(PG:3)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.cancel(PG:8)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.aj.a(PG:2)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.l(PG:3)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.cancel(PG:8)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.m(PG:2)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.c.a(PG:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.l(PG:3)
                                                                                                        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.d.cancel(PG:8)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.s3.o.c(PG:2)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.s3.r.a(PG:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.dc.a.c.e(PG:2)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.dc.a.c.c(PG:3)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.dc.a.e.a(PG:5)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.s3.n.hh(PG:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.cd.g.a.f.e(PG:2)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.k.a.g.d(PG:22)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.k.a.g.ks(PG:6)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.s3.o.e(PG:14)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.s3.p.run(PG:1)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:487)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.e.run(PG:2)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bi.run(PG:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bi.run(PG:1)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.l.run(PG:5)
2023-09-07 14:58:40.243   621-8752  GnssPsdsDownloader      system_server                        E  No Long-Term PSDS servers were specified in the GnssConfiguration
2023-09-07 15:00:00.106  8754-8754  ndroid.settings         pid-8754                             E  Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2023-09-07 15:00:00.602   621-672   system_server           system_server                        E  Cannot read thread CPU times for PID 621
2023-09-07 15:00:24.191  8419-8439  SingleInst...teListener com.android.systemui                 E  Failed remote call on null listener
2023-09-07 15:00:24.994  8419-8453  OpenGLRenderer          com.android.systemui                 E  Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
2023-09-07 15:00:26.026  8490-8526  OpenGLRenderer          com...le.android.apps.nexuslauncher  E  Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
2023-09-07 15:00:27.888  7824-8845  OpenGLRenderer          com....android.googlequicksearchbox  E  Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
2023-09-07 15:00:28.357  8822-8849  OpenGLRenderer          com.project.bt                   E  Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
2023-09-07 15:00:28.388   621-4563  TaskPersister           system_server                        E  File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
2023-09-07 15:00:28.830  8419-8453  OpenGLRenderer          com.android.systemui                 E  Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
2023-09-07 15:00:28.956  8490-8526  FrameEvents             com...le.android.apps.nexuslauncher  E  updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
2023-09-07 15:00:30.005  8868-8868  .apps.wallpaper         pid-8868                             E  Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2023-09-07 15:00:30.733  8490-8526  FrameEvents             com...le.android.apps.nexuslauncher  E  updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
2023-09-07 15:00:37.365  8822-8976  .project.bt         com.project.bt                   E  Attempt to load writable dex file: /data/local/tmp/perfd/sqlite-inspection.jar
2023-09-07 15:00:37.366  8822-8977  .project.bt         com.project.bt                   E  Attempt to load writable dex file: /data/local/tmp/perfd/backgroundtask-inspection.jar
2023-09-07 15:00:37.370  8822-8978  .project.bt         com.project.bt                   E  Attempt to load writable dex file: /data/local/tmp/perfd/network-inspector.jar
```

Comment: Have you added appropriate permissions? Also, check logcat for relevant error logs.

Comment: I added the BLUETOOTH permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I am getting this error when I click on OFF button  "Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission for AttributionSource { uid = 10183, packageName = com.project.btseat, attributionTag = null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@786c51d, next = null }: disable". However, I have already added it.

Comment: Besides declaring permissions in manifest, you need to also ask user: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: Am I not doing that using the "ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult( ..." an example code base on my current one would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can read here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions :

> The BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE, BLUETOOTH_CONNECT, and BLUETOOTH_SCAN
> permissions are runtime permissions. Therefore, you must explicitly
> request user approval in your app before you can look for Bluetooth
> devices, make a device discoverable to other devices, or communicate
> with already-paired Bluetooth devices.

To ask for permissions, add in your onCreate of activity below code. Before asking you actually should also explain why you need those permissions.

```
    // Check if any is not granted
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Ask for them
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
                        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
                        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
                },
                REQUEST_ID);
    }
    else {
        // You can use BT code here 
    }
```

then override onRequestPermissionsResult, it will be called with the result whether user aproved your request:

```
   @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ID) {
            for (int grantResult : grantResults) {
                if (grantResult != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // User rejected, you might explain to user more why you need this permission, and maybe add button to ask for it again.
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    // Ok, from now on you can use BT code
                }
            }
        }
```

REQUEST_ID is some int constant

[edit]
In you new code your function:

```
private boolean hasPermissions(String[] permissions) {
    if (permissions != null){
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d("PERMISSIONS", "Permission is not granted: " + permission);
            }
            return true;
        }
    return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

is wrong - it always returns true, you should return false when any of the permission is not granted. Something like this:

```
for (String permission : permissions) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.d("PERMISSIONS", "Permission is not granted: " + permission);
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

[edit2]

I spent some time on writing a sample appliation doing simple thing of turning BT on and off. It appears that a lot of code are the permissions handling. You can find full repository on github: https://github.com/luskan/btturnonoffapp

Comment: This code snippet seems to be deprecated. I'm trying to use ActivityResultLauncher. I have updated my original code with some improvements but still not showing any message to allow bluetooth permissions and ON/OFF Buttons not responding.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @marcinj. I updated the code following your advices. It's still not working as expected and updated the logcat in my initial question. Most probably I'll have to spend more time debugging this issue as it's my first app in android studio. Is there any resource I can use to find the errors I'm getting in the logcat logs?

Comment: @SemirAdam I dont see in this logcat anything related to your app - you can create new SO questions about exceptions you get. Mostly, when exceptions related to your app will be put into logcat - they will include some lines with your package name leading to your source code lines. For debugging  guides see here : https://developer.android.com/studio/debug. I have also put on github sample BT app, see my second edit. Have fun with coding! :-)